# Handling Xpaths and Submitting Webforms using Requests and lxml

Tags: xml, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

Hello I am currently working on a program that will submit a phone number to a reverse phone number website and then follow the correct Xpath to determine whether the phone is wwireless or not.

The xpath of the element is

```
//*[@id="content"]/fieldset/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/strong
```

my code thus far is

```
def Phone_Checker(number):
    url = 'http://www.reversephonelookup.com/'
    data={'Enter Number': number}
    r = requests.post(url, data=data)
    tree=html.fromstring(r.content)
    Service_type=tree.xpath('//fieldset[@id="content"]/text()')
    print(Service_type)
    if "wireless" in Service_type:
        print(True)
        return True
    else: 
        print(False)
        return False
```

I was just wondering am I inputting my xpath wrong and if my code should submit the phone number correctly as well I am a mediocre programmer and would like to know how I would be able to make this code function as I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is missing quite a lot of necessary data and steps, when I first looked I saw the page was using a lot of javascript but monitoring the requests I saw you can actually get it using requests, first we need to post to:

*`http://www.reversephonelookup.com/results.php`*, with the correct post data:

[image]

Once we have done that we need to make a get request to *`http://www.reversephonelookup.com/number/the_number`*:

[image]

So putting that all together:

```
def Phone_Checker(number):
    head = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"}
    url = 'http://www.reversephonelookup.com/results.php'
    data = {"phone": number, "image.x": "26", "image.y": "37"}
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.post(url, data=data, headers=head)
        r = s.get("http://www.reversephonelookup.com/number/{}/".format(number),headers=head)
        tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
        Service_type = tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]//fieldset//text()')
        return  "wireless" in Service_type


Phone_Checker("2068675309")
```

`return Service_type and "wireless" in Service_type` will only return True if wireless is a string in list. I also tweaked your xpath to get all the text.

A more useful way to use the function would be to return the lxml tree:

```
def Phone_Checker(number):
    head = {
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"}
    url = 'http://www.reversephonelookup.com/results.php'
    data = {"phone": number, "image.x": "26", "image.y": "37"}
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.post(url, data=data, headers=head)
        r = s.get("http://www.reversephonelookup.com/number/{}/".format(number),headers=head)
    return html.fromstring(r.content)
```

Then:

```
xml = Phone_Checker(....)
```

An example:

```
In [5]: xml = Phone_Checker("8598795756")


In [6]: print(xml.xpath("//fieldset//tr/td[text()='Original Service Type:']/following::strong/text()"))
['Landline', 'Independent Telephone Company', 'Versailles, KY', 'VRSLKYXADS0']
```

The first result is the type of connection, which if you just want that you can use:

```
"//fieldset//tr/td[text()='Original Service Type:']/following::strong[1]/text()"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help ! I found your answer very helpful however, when I use the method described in your second code it only works if I have phone_checker(number) however when I try to access the module from a different code to iterate through a list of phone numbers it returns me an error that lxml has no module fromstring but I do not receive that error otherwise, do you know what the source of this problem possibly could be?

Comment: @AugustCosta, did you call your script lxml.py by any chance?

Comment: @Padriac Cunningham, No I did not I edited my post to better give you a sense of the new problem I have

Comment: @AugustCosta, better to ask a new question with the full details, you can link to this question for context. Also pasting the traceback is better than using images.